# Identity Server SameSite=None cannot login

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm working on an application that uses IdentityServer 4 and .Net 5 I created the project based on the 'with React.js' with Individual Authentication template.

[image]

Everything works correctly when I run the application locally, if I run it through docker however, when I attempt to login something silently fails and redirects me back to the login screen

[image]

My only guess is something with the authentication cookies are messed up as I'm seeing these messages when the login/redirect happens

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseCookies[1]
      The cookie 'Identity.External' has set 'SameSite=None' and must also set 'Secure'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseCookies[1]
      The cookie 'idsrv.session' has set 'SameSite=None' and must also set 'Secure'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseCookies[1]
      The cookie '.AspNetCore.Identity.Application' has set 'SameSite=None' and must also set 'Secure'.
```

I've attempted to change the cookies `SecurePolicy` to `CookieSecurePolicy.Always`

```
                services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddIdentityServerJwt()
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();
                        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                    });
```

But it didn't have any affect, any idea as to why this issue is happening?

Thanks

Comment: you must use HTTPS, to be able to set a cookie as samesite=none (secure cookie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it like in [Scoruba's Identity Server](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin/).

It works good for me.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
        AuthenticationHelpers.CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
    options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
        AuthenticationHelpers.CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
});

public static class AuthenticationHelpers
  {
    public static void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
    {
      if (options.SameSite != SameSiteMode.None)
        return;
      string userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
      if (httpContext.Request.IsHttps && !AuthenticationHelpers.DisallowsSameSiteNone(userAgent))
        return;
      options.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    }

    public static bool DisallowsSameSiteNone(string userAgent) => userAgent.Contains("CPU iPhone OS 12") || userAgent.Contains("iPad; CPU OS 12") || userAgent.Contains("Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14") && userAgent.Contains("Version/") && userAgent.Contains("Safari") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/5") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6");
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin/blob/f993f64a14c08d6c00b2109dfda9b1b5a299282e/src/Skoruba.IdentityServer4.STS.Identity/Helpers/StartupHelpers.cs#L284